# Connecting resources to Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-gov

Just getting started with Log Analytics.  What will happen if I enable Diagnostics Logging in a VM which will send the data to a storage account that I then connect to Log Analytics and then also connect the VM directly to Log Analytics?

Comment: Great question! Documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-azure-storage-iis-table#use-the-azure-portal-to-collect-logs-from-azure-storage) only states "you are able to see data from the storage account in Log Analytics"